# Scheduled Powershell Task, stuck Running

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have problems when running a powershell script in Scheduled Tasks. It gets stuck in Running, even though the Transcript has logged out the last row "Done!" and it also looks like it has done exactly what i want it to. What am I missing?

When running it from `Run` in Windows it also seems fine: `powershell -file "D:\_temp\copy_bat\copy_one_reprint_folder.ps1"`

Seetings in Task Scheduler is:

- Run with full priviliges
- Run weither user is logged on or not
- Action, start program `powershell.exe`

  - `-file "D:\_temp\copy_bat\copy_one_reprint_folder.ps1"`

[image: Stuck in Running]
[image: History in TS]

Please see code below if needed.

```
# PowerShell RePRINT copy first folder, sorted on lastModified
function timestamp
{
    $ts = Get-Date -format s
    return $ts
}

$fromDirectory = "D:\_temp\copy_bat"
$toDirectory = "D:\_temp\in_dummy"
$extractGUIDdir = ""
$docTypeDir = ""

# Logging
#########
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path $fromDirectory\copy_one_reprint_folder.log.txt -append
###########


Write-Host ""
Write-Host (timestamp) "Copy RePRINT extract started"
Write-Host (timestamp) "============================"

Get-ChildItem -path $fromDirectory | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort-Object CreationTime | `
    Where-Object {$_.name -ne "_copied"} | `
    Select-Object -first 1 | `
        Foreach-Object{
            Write-Host (timestamp) $_.name
            $extractGUIDdir = $_.FullName
            Get-ChildItem -path $extractGUIDdir |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "Purchase Order \(-999999997\)" -or $_.Name -match "Logistics documents \(-1000000000\)" -or $_.Name -match "Specifications \(-999999998\)"} | `
                Foreach-Object{
                    Write-Host (timestamp) "  " $_.Name
                }
            Write-Host ""

            Write-Host "These folders (document types), were also found but will not be included"
            Get-ChildItem -path $extractGUIDdir -Exclude "Logistics documents (-1000000000)", "Purchase Order (-999999997)", "Specifications (-999999998)" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | `
                Foreach-Object{
                    Write-Host (timestamp) " - " $_.name
                }
            Write-Host ""

            Get-ChildItem -path $extractGUIDdir | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "Purchase Order \(-999999997\)" -or $_.Name -match "Logistics documents \(-1000000000\)" -or $_.Name -match "Specifications \(-999999998\)"} | `
                Foreach-Object{
                        $temp_name = $_.FullName
                        Write-Host (timestamp) "copying files from " $_.FullName
                        Write-Host (timestamp) "                    to "  $toDirectory
                        #Copy-Item ($_.FullName)\*.* $toDirectory
                        Write-Host (timestamp) " copying meta-files..."
                        Copy-Item $temp_name\*.meta $toDirectory -Filter *.meta
                        Write-Host (timestamp) " copying pdf-files..."
                        Copy-Item $temp_name\*.pdf $toDirectory -Filter *.pdf
                        if(Test-Path $temp_name\*.* -Exclude *.meta, *.pdf)
                        {
                            Write-Host (timestamp) " WARNING/ERROR not all documents have been moved. Only PDFs was moved!"
                            Write-Host (timestamp) " Check folder for other document-types."
                        }
                }
                Move-Item $extractGUIDdir $fromDirectory\_copied
        }

Write-Host (timestamp) " DONE!"

# Stop logging
Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is solved.

It works, stupid me did not press `F5`(update) in task scheduler to update the status of the task in the gui.

Actually I was quite certain I did this, but apparently not.

Comment: The most stupid thing is that the UI is only partially event-driven, so we see automatically when it starts and not when it finishes. I wasted one hour on this problem.